# Custom version of bootstrap using webpack/laravel mix?

Tags: laravel, webpack, bootstrap-4, laravel-mix

I'm trying to create a custom build of bootstrap 4 using webpack, but it won't compile.

I have bootstrap 4 here:

```
/node_modules/bootstrap/scss
```

I create my own app.scss file to import the various parts of bootstrap that I want:

```
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "custom";
....
```

In my webpack file I have:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', null, { includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/'] });
```

I've also tried:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', { includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/'] });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import bootstrap in app.scss with:

```
..
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables"
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins"
..
```

The `~bootstrap` is resloved to the npm package. This way you won't have to configure the mix file.

Comment: Thanks, what does the ~ actually mean, look in the node modules folder?

Comment: yes, it is a functionality provided by the loaders of webpack.